# Trigger CSS animation on div's height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been trying to trigger a Animate.css animation on scroll. I managed on my page using the following jquery code. It works fine:

```
    $(function() {

  var $window           = $(window),
      win_height_padded = $window.height() * 1.1,
      isTouch           = Modernizr.touch;

  if (isTouch) { $('.revealOnScroll').addClass('animated'); }

  $window.on('scroll', revealOnScroll);

  function revealOnScroll() {
    var scrolled = $window.scrollTop(),
        win_height_padded = $window.height() * 1.1;

    // Showed...
    $(".revealOnScroll:not(.animated)").each(function () {
      var $this     = $(this),
          offsetTop = $this.offset().top;

      if (scrolled + win_height_padded > offsetTop+300) {
        if ($this.data('timeout')) {
          window.setTimeout(function(){
            $this.addClass('animated ' + $this.data('animation'));
          }, parseInt($this.data('timeout'),10));
        } else {
          $this.addClass('animated ' + $this.data('animation'));
        }
      }
    });
    // Hidden...
   $(".revealOnScroll.animated").each(function (index) {
      var $this     = $(this),
          offsetTop = $this.offset().top;
      if (scrolled + win_height_padded < offsetTop) {
        $(this).removeClass('animated hinge fadeInLeft fadeIn pulse')
      }
    });
  }

  revealOnScroll();
});
```

However I have an image opening a fullscreen div. I would like to use that same effect when scrolling down inside my div.

I have tried to change "window" with the name of my div but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your selector dos't exist see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Comment: It does exist. I'm sure about this. However it is still linked to the second page (the one behind the div)

Comment: is set height and width to your div and overflow is scroll?

Comment: Yes everything is set as you said. But I have a scroll inside a hidden overflow (to prevent the overflow of the main page). I don't know if that's the issue.